# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webservice'

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, pip, devops

Even after installing the module using

```
pip3 install webservice
```

I still get the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webservice'

I did use a virtual env.
installed all necessary packages using pip3 install

```
python3 server.py
```

gives:  File "server.py", line 15, in 
import webservice.utils as web_utils
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webservice.utils'; 'webservice' is not a package

Comment: you probably are not installing in the right python environment

Comment: how are you running your python code? from console or from some software like Pycharm?

Comment: I'm running it on ubuntu 18.0.4

Comment: please write down all your steps. Are you using a virtual env?

Comment: If you used a virtual env your file must be in the env

Comment: yes it is in the env

Comment: After trying to run it in the env.
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webservice.utils'; 'webservice' is not a package
This is the error

Answer (score 0):

This error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webservice.utils'; 'webservice' is not a package` may also occur if you have named the main program file you created as `webservice.py` and try to run it as `python webservice.py` or another file has the name `webservice.py` in the same folder from which you run your program. Python will consider your program file as a module and try to find something in it that is naturally not in it. About where Python is looking for modules, see [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path).

In this case, rename your program file so that its name does not equal with the name of the imported module.